# Centos network manager how to automatically start enp6s0

Tags: networking, boot, centos, centos-7

for some reason i always need to manually activate my network connection on my centos machine after every reboot. I have to type in the nmtui command and activate enp6s0, is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a file called ifcfg-enp6s0 in your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ directory ? There should be a variable called ONBOOT=yes.